# .net core calls to WSDL Web Service get empty array (single object works fine)

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, soap, wsdl

i'am using a soap web service generated by apache axis in a .net core 3.1 application.

Complex type works fine but I have a problem when return type is an array: they are always empty, i test web service with a demo client and it works fine with parameters i'am using

The invocation of  ws:

```
var roles = await cli.getProfiliApplicativiAsync("APP", "UTE", "USER_ID");
```

`roles ?.Body?.getProfiliApplicativiReturn?.role` has 0 elements

This are the relevant wsdl part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://xxx" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://xxx" xmlns:intf="http://xxx" xmlns:tns1="http://dto.xxx" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xxx" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://dto.xxx"/>
   <element name="getProfiliApplicativi">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="applicazione" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="tipo" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="userid" type="xsd:string"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="getProfiliApplicativiResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="getProfiliApplicativiReturn" type="tns1:ProfileList"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <complexType name="ArrayOf_tns1_Profile">
    <sequence>
     <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="tns1:Profile"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
</schema>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://dto.xxx" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://xxx"/>
   <complexType name="ServiceBase">
    <sequence/>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="Profile">
    <sequence>
     <element name="codRuolo" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="descrProfilo" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="ordine" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="ruolo" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="ProfileList">
    <complexContent>
     <extension base="tns1:ServiceBase">
      <sequence>
       <element name="desc_esito" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
       <element name="role" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_tns1_Profile"/>
      </sequence>
     </extension>
    </complexContent>
   </complexType>
</schema>
 </wsdl:types>

     <wsdl:message name="getProfiliApplicativiRequest">

          <wsdl:part element="intf:getProfiliApplicativi" name="parameters"/>

     </wsdl:message>

     <wsdl:message name="getProfiliApplicativiResponse">

          <wsdl:part element="intf:getProfiliApplicativiResponse" name="parameters"/>

     </wsdl:message>



<wsdl:portType name="Inquiry">

          <wsdl:operation name="getProfiliApplicativi">

               <wsdl:input message="intf:getProfiliApplicativiRequest" name="getProfiliApplicativiRequest"/>

               <wsdl:output message="intf:getProfiliApplicativiResponse" name="getProfiliApplicativiResponse"/>

          </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>



      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="getProfiliApplicativi">

           <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

           <wsdl:input name="getProfiliApplicativiRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

           </wsdl:input>

           <wsdl:output name="getProfiliApplicativiResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

           </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>
```

and c# translations

```
namespace SpaWS
{
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "ServiceBase", Namespace = "http://dto.xxx")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(SpaWS.ProfileList))]
public partial class ServiceBase : object
{
}    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http:/xxx", ConfigurationName = "SpaWS.Inquiry")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface Inquiry
    {
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiResponse>  getProfiliApplicativiAsync(SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequest request);
}



[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "ProfileList", Namespace = "http://dto.business.spa.intesasanpaolo.com")]
public partial class ProfileList : SpaWS.ServiceBase
{

    private string desc_esitoField;

    private SpaWS.ArrayOf_tns1_Profile roleField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = true)]
    public string desc_esito
    {
        get
        {
            return this.desc_esitoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.desc_esitoField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = true)]
    public SpaWS.ArrayOf_tns1_Profile role
    {
        get
        {
            return this.roleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.roleField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name = "ArrayOf_tns1_Profile", Namespace = "http://business.spa.intesasanpaolo.com", ItemName = "item")]
public class ArrayOf_tns1_Profile : System.Collections.Generic.List<SpaWS.Profile>
{
}









[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class getProfiliApplicativiRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "getProfiliApplicativi", Namespace = "http://xxx", Order = 0)]
    public SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequestBody Body;

    public getProfiliApplicativiRequest()
    {
    }

    public getProfiliApplicativiRequest(SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequestBody Body)
    {
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]  

[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx")]
public partial class getProfiliApplicativiRequestBody
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 0)]
    public string applicazione;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 1)]
    public string tipo;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 2)]
    public string userid;

    public getProfiliApplicativiRequestBody()
    {
    }

    public getProfiliApplicativiRequestBody(string applicazione, string tipo, string userid)
    {
        this.applicazione = applicazione;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.userid = userid;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]

 [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class getProfiliApplicativiResponse
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "getProfiliApplicativiResponse", Namespace = "http://xxx", Order = 0)]
    public SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiResponseBody Body;

    public getProfiliApplicativiResponse()
    {
    }

    public getProfiliApplicativiResponse(SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiResponseBody Body)
    {
        this.Body = Body;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx")]
public partial class getProfiliApplicativiResponseBody
{

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 0)]
    public SpaWS.ProfileList getProfiliApplicativiReturn;

    public getProfiliApplicativiResponseBody()
    {
    }

    public getProfiliApplicativiResponseBody(SpaWS.ProfileList getProfiliApplicativiReturn)
    {
        this.getProfiliApplicativiReturn = getProfiliApplicativiReturn;
    }
}



[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiResponse> SpaWS.Inquiry.getProfiliApplicativiAsync(SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequest request)
        {
            return base.Channel.getProfiliApplicativiAsync(request);
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiResponse> getProfiliApplicativiAsync(string applicazione, string tipo, string userid)
        {
            SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequest inValue = new SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequest();
            inValue.Body = new SpaWS.getProfiliApplicativiRequestBody();
            inValue.Body.applicazione = applicazione;
            inValue.Body.tipo = tipo;
            inValue.Body.userid = userid;
            return ((SpaWS.Inquiry)(this)).getProfiliApplicativiAsync(inValue);
        }
```

Comment: added a missing type in c# impl

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the WSDL, I see no definition for `getElencoUfficiAsync` or office array.

In fact, the WSDL contain reference for `getProfiliApplicativi`, `profileList`, `arrayOf_tns1_profile` - that's about it. I would recommend checking your WSDL and see that the method actually exists.

If so, you need to make sure you define your complex types properly through your scheme.

Comment: sorry, i paste the wrong methods call: i have same problem for many method like the one i post here. now i have updated question using getProfiliApplicativi everywhere

Comment: There is no reference for an async method in the scheme as well, check the sync method and see if the info returns.

Comment: .net svcutils create all method only as async  but one's that return single object works, only array are always empty

Comment: i'am investigating if there is a way to read raw response xml and manually bind it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with arrays being empty.  The solution for me was to set SoapOptions.SoapSerializer to XmlSerializer.  It wasn't working with DataContractSerializer.

After doing this, the arrays were populated.

We were using the SoapCore Nuget package.